# How to get default value of dropdown input in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am trying to get the default value of dropdown input field as I am using it for both add and update. Below is my code

```js
<BrInput
    type="select"
    name="altPayableInd"
    id="altPayableInd"
    options={altPayableIndOpt}
    default={payableResp.payable[index] && payableResp.payable[index].altPayableInd.value && this.setDefaultValue(payableResp.payable[index] && payableResp.payable[index].altPayableInd.value, altPayableIndOpt)}
/>
```

```js
setDefaultValue = (value, options) => {
    let matchedLabel = options.find(el => el.value === value);
    if (value !== "O") {
        this.setState({ viewReason: false })
    }
    return [{ value, label: matchedLabel.label }]
}
```

error :

> Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Seems like you're calling setDefaultValue in render method which updates the component state. Try giving a default 'value' and adding a 'onChange' handler to your drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should use only `get` methods when you are setting `prop` values in `render`.

In `setDefaultValue` you are using `setState`, which becomes invalid, thats what your error says. **You have to move this to some another logic**. 
To make this work as it is, use as this: (code is commented here, just to show error part, you can remove this)

```
setDefaultValue = (value, options) => {
    let matchedLabel = options.find(el => el.value === value);
    // if (value !== "O") {
    //     this.setState({ viewReason: false }) // you can't use setState in render
    // }
    return [{ value, label: matchedLabel.label }]
}
```